# Android - Switching between 5 activities and retaining state of first activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arcgis

I have 5 different activities.

The first activity is my application's first page. It has an navigation bar on top which allows me to move between all 5 activities. (The navigation bar is present in all activity's xml layout)

The problem I am facing is whenever I am moving to another activity (e.g. Activity 1 to Activity 2) before going back (Activity 2 to Activity 1), my Activity 1 will not render the MapView in it. The MapView works fine when the application has not switch activities.

I am currently using this code to move between activities:

Code in Activity 1

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
```

Code in Activity 2

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class));
```

Currently the only way I manage to move back to activity 1 is by pressing the phone's back button.But I will face another problem.

In the event when I move between more than 2 activities (e.g. Activity 1 to Activity 2 and to Activity 3), the back button will make it go from Activity 3 to Activity 2 and finally to Activity 1. (I found some examples on stackoverflow to overcome this issue)

Is the cause of the main problem of the MapView not rendering due to me not configuring it correctly?

Or is it caused by the way I switch between activities?

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, I suggest you investigate the method and parameters to `Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_???)`

For instance, in your example you could do:

Code in Activity 1

```
// No change here
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
```

Code in Activity 2

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

This will stop a stack of Activities building up and requiring lots of Back buttons to exit the app. With your 5 activities, your main Activity1 should use the default to launch Activity2, 3, 4, and 5, and all other Activities should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to switch between themselves and back to Activity1.

For your second problem, we need more information - may I suggest that you actually delete the question from here and repost it as a separate query, along with the relevant code and LogCat output. It is most likely not directly connected with starting activities.

Comment: Hi Mr Ken, I have tried your suggestion and received positive response. The MapView is able to display my mapLayer. But it seems to be abit inconsistent where the mapLayer may display a already loaded map (a fully loaded map is displayed) or it starts to load the map from the ArcGis map server (visual signs that the map is loading). Another problem is although my mapLayer is able to display, my graphicsLayer is still missing. I have tested if my MapView contains the graphicsLayer and if there is any contents (graphics) in the graphicsLayer and both returned positive.